# Set Spring boot yaml configuration list property via environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I am configuring my Spring Boot application with an application.yml file:

```
foo:
  bar: foobar
foolist:
- bar: foobar1
  baz: foobaz1
- bar: foobar1
  baz: foobaz1
```

I can easily set the foo.bar value with an environment variable, e.g.

```
export FOO_BAR=value
```

How can I set values of the foolist entrie? `FOOLIST[0]_BAR` is not a valid identifier and `FOOLIST_0_BAR` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to provide arbitrary JSON object in the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` environment variable:

```
export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"foolist":[{"bar": "foobar1", "baz: foobaz1"}, {"bar": "foobar2", "baz: foobaz2"}]}'
```

Documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html